# Xamarin Android custom title for my view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, viewmodel, mvvmcross

Hi I want to set my title view to match with the current article title.

I tried that but I get a null exception because the ViewModel isn't load before the View

ArticleView.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate(bundle);

   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ArticleView);

   var vm = this.ViewModel as ArticleViewModel;
   this.Title = vm.CurrentArticle.Name;
}
```

I navigate to an Article from a MvxGridView

```
<MvxGridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listitemarticles1"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ArticlesCollection;ItemClick ShowArticleCommand"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/articletemplate" />
```

Edit :

Is it a good way to change remove my actionbar Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" to Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" and to create my actionbar in the axml where I can set a Text binding to CurrentArticle.Name ?

Comment: Hmm.. that's odd. The _ViewModel_ should be available during _OnCreate_. Are you sure it's the ViewModel that is null? Did you check to see if _CurrentArticle_ is null instead?

Comment: It is CurrentArticle which is null but I init it in my ViewModel

Comment: When do you initialize it? Do you have an _Init_ method? _Init_ and _Start_ are called before _OnCreate_. It would be helpful if you posted your _ViewModel_ code.

Comment: You can bind the view `Title` using a code-behind `CreateBinding` statement (just like in iOS) - but without a bit more info on your `ViewModel` I'm not sure if that will help you or not